# An android.app.Application.onCreate() Call for an InstantApp Feature

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

PROBLEM: Need to initialize some objects before an activity from secondary (non-base) Instant App feature is launched.

RESEARCH: In base feature we can create *`android.app.Application`* class and declare it in the base features's *`Manifest`*:

```
  <application
    android:name="com.example.MyApplicationOfBaseFeature">
```

As a result, *`android.app.Application.onCreate()`* method will be called before any other activity's *`onCreate()`*.

But adding the same to secondary feature results in `Manifest` merge error:

```
   <application
     android:name="com.example.MyApplicationOfSecondaryFeature">
```

QUESTION: **How do I do the same for a secondary feature in my Instant App**?

Comment: Your secondary feature uses the application class of the base feature. What is the merge error?

Comment: I wonder if I could have a similar application class for a second feature. It is a matter of circular referencing of features, when using classes from each other. Separating Application.onCreate() preinitialisations could keep features unbinded and solve the problem. Merge error is as is "Manifest merge error".

Comment: I think you are trying to do something that goes against the Instant App architecture. Is there another option to achieve what you are looking for? What is your actual goal?